# 'form.is_valid()' fails when I want to save form with choices based on two models

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-validation

I want to let users to choose their countries. I have 2 models = `Countries` with some figures and `CountriesTranslations`. I am trying to make tuple with `country` (because user has FK to this model) and its `translation`. In front-end I see dropdown list of countries, but when I try to save the form, I see
error: `Exception Value: Cannot assign "'AF'": "UserProfile.country" must be a "Countries" instance.`
Error happens at the line `if user_profile_form.is_valid():`

```
# admindivisions.models
class Countries(models.Model):
    osm_id = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField()
    population = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    iso3166_1 = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    iso3166_1_a2 = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    iso3166_1_a3 = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'admindivisions_countries'
        verbose_name = 'Country'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Countries'

class CountriesTranslations(models.Model):
    common_name = models.CharField(max_length=81, blank=True, db_index=True)
    formal_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    country = models.ForeignKey(Countries, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Details of Country')
    lang_group = models.ForeignKey(LanguagesGroups, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Language of Country',
                                   null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'admindivisions_countries_translations'
        verbose_name = 'Country Translation'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Countries Translations'

# profiles.forms
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # PREPARE CHOICES
    country_choices = ()
    lang_group = Languages.objects.get(iso_code='en').group
    for country in Countries.objects.filter(status=1):
        eng_name = country.countriestranslations_set.filter(lang_group=lang_group).first()
        if eng_name:
            country_choices += ((country, eng_name.common_name),)
    country_choices = sorted(country_choices, key=lambda tup: tup[1])

    country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=country_choices, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile()
        fields = ('email', 'email_privacy',
                  'profile_url',
                  'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'country',)

# profiles.views
def profile_settings(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if user_profile_form.is_valid():
            user_profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Your profile was successfully updated!'))

            return redirect('settings')

        else:
            messages.error(request, _('Please correct the error below.'))

    else:
        user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user)

    return render(request, 'profiles/profiles_settings.html', {
        'user_profile_form': user_profile_form,
    })
```

As I understand, `country` from `((country, eng_name.common_name),)` is converted to `str`. What is the right way to keep `country instance` in the form? or if I am doing it in the wrong way, what way is correct?

**EDITED**:
As a possible solution is to use `ModelChoiceField` with overriding `label_from_instance` as shown below:

```
class CountriesChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, user_lang='en', *args, **kwargs):
        super(CountriesChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user_lang = user_lang

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.countriestranslations_set.get(lang_group=self.user_lang)

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
user_lang = user_lang_here
country = CountriesChoiceField(
    queryset=Countries.objects.filter(
        status=1, iso3166_1__isnull=False,
        countriestranslations__lang_group=user_lang).order_by('countriestranslations__common_name'),
    widget=forms.Select(), user_lang=user_lang)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile()
        fields = ('email', 'email_privacy',
                  'profile_url',
                  'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'country',)
```

but this solution produces too much queries because of the query in `label_from_instance` and page loads too slowly. Would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be solved.

The version below produces `7 queries in 29.45ms` vs `73 queries in 92.52ms` in the **EDITED** above. I think it is possible to make it even faster if to set `unique_together` for some fields.

```
class CountriesChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, user_lang, *args, **kwargs):

        queryset = Countries.objects.filter(
            status=1, iso3166_1__isnull=False,
            countriestranslations__lang_group=user_lang).order_by('countriestranslations__common_name')

        super(CountriesChoiceField, self).__init__(queryset, *args, **kwargs)

        self.translations = OrderedDict()
        for country in queryset:
            name = country.countriestranslations_set.get(lang_group=user_lang).common_name
            self.translations[country] = name

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return self.translations[obj]

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user_lang = user_lang_here
    country = CountriesChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), user_lang=user_lang)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile()
        fields = ('email', 'email_privacy',
                  'profile_url',
                  'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'country',)
```

So, now it is possible to have choices based on two (2) models with a good speed. Also the DRY principle is applied, so if there is a need to use choices multiple times in different forms - no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [forms.ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) instead of the forms.ChoiceField for your dropdown list.

The ModelChoiceField builds based on a QuerySet and preserves the model instance.

Comment: The problem is that I need to combine data from 2 models - I need to get `country` instance from `Countries` model, and its `translation` from `CountriesTranslations` model (this one is shown to users). If I understand correctly, `ModelChoiceField` can't provide Translated name of country in my case, just `country` instance itself.

Comment: The optional argument `to_field_name` seems to allow you to customize the display name. I am not sure how flexible that feature is, but it think it might be worth trying to set up and i think that you will be able to put something dynamically calculated in there, as long as it is in the syntax of the HTML templating language

Comment: Just tried. Does not wok. `to_field_name`, as I can understand, just changes html `option value` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name